# "localhost" always shows "welcome to Nginx" Ubuntu?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, lamp

I am running Ubuntu 16. I am fairly new to web design but I have set up a LAMP server on my Ubuntu machine and installed WordPress site. I wanted to try to mess around with PHP so I tried to install myphp.

I managed to do this and I realized that I had to install nginx also.

I did this, but my local host always diverts to a message "welcome to Nginx"

I tried to edit the configuration files but could not get it to work?

Is there a guide for installing Nginx and myphp to see phpMyAdmin, after you have already set up a WordPress site?

Like I said I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to delete the index.html file from the web root. The index.php file should remain.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu+nginx go to html directory using following command

`cd /var/www/html/`

then find out following `index.nginx-debian.html` and delete it or edit it as you want

1. To edit these file open into you editor or use Ubuntu default editor `nano`.

   `sudo nano /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html`
2. To delete these file run following command.

   `sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html`

these is the defautl nginx welcome page that why it appear after install, for more information check nginx default configuration file using following command.
`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Thanks